# Applying probability model

Tags: probability, self-study

This question is from my textbook and I want to review the answer (no answer since its even numbered).

> Suppose $S = \{1,2,3\}$, with $P(\{1\}) = 1/2$ and $P(\{1,2\}) = 2/3$. What must $P(\{2\})$ be?

I believe the answer is $1/6$, since you do $P(\{1,2\}) = P(\{1\}) + P(\{2\})$ and rearrange to solve for $P(\{2\})$. However, I'm confused as to if the events $P(\{1\})$ and $P(\{2\})$ are disjoint or not; it doesn't mention anything in the question, so should I just assume they're disjoint?

Comment: "the events P({1}) and P({2})". P is probability. {1} and {2} are events. Based on P({1,2}) = 2/3, can you get if the events {1} and {2} are disjoint or not?

Comment: If $S = \{1,2,3\}$ is a sample space, then singleton (or elementary) events $\{1\},\{2\},$ and $\{3\}$ are mutually disjoint. Also, as you are on the way to showing, their respective probabilities are $1/2, 1/6,$ and $1/3.$

Comment: Your question asks whether $1$ and $2$ are the same or not.  What is your answer?

Comment: Consider instead the experiment of flipping a coin with  S={H,T}. It is ever possible for a flip to land heads and tails at the same time? If not {H} and {T} are disjoint. Now imagine a die with three sides, and you have the experiment mentioned above. Could a three-sided die ever land on both {1} and {2} at the same time? Maybe adding physical context will give more intuition about these types of problems, which, I agree, can be confusing.